# Count of Task based on Students and count of task by students by Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I achieved the count of each tasks performed by Students from the below Query. In addition I also need to get the count based on tasks performed by students by date on the same query itself. How can I achieve it?

```
SELECT  DISTINCT Date
             , Task_Name[Task Performed]
             , Student_Name [Name]
             , COUNT(Name)[Count]
    FROM Datamining.dbo.Registry 

GROUP BY Date, Task_Name, Student_Name
```

The result for above query is

```
Date          Task Performed     Name           Count
10/1/2021     A                  Joseph         2
10/1/2021     B                  Sherin         3
10/2/2021     A                  Joseph         1
10/2/2021     B                  Sherin         2
10/3/2021     A                  Joseph         3
10/3/2021     B                  Sherin         3
```

Expected Results

```
Date          Task Performed     Name           Count     Total Count by Date
10/1/2021     A                  Joseph         2         5
10/1/2021     B                  Sherin         3         5
10/2/2021     A                  Joseph         1         3
10/2/2021     B                  Sherin         2         3
10/3/2021     A                  Joseph         3         6
10/3/2021     B                  Sherin         3         6
```

How this expected results can be achieved from the above query.

Comment: Have you tried `count(*) over (partition by date)`?

Comment: partition by date gives me count as 2,2,2 based on the above results

Comment: You must be applying the `count over()` to the results you show above, rather than the raw data.

Comment: DISTINCT does nothing useful in your first query since you are grouping on the three selected columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did it using an inner query:
Also `Distinct` is not needed so I deleted it:

```
SELECT   r.Date
         , r.Task_Name[Task Performed]
         , r.Student_Name [Name]
         , COUNT(r.Name)[Count]
         ,(
         select count(*) from  Datamining.dbo.Registry rr
         where rr.Date = r.Date
         group by date 
         )  TotalCountByDate         
FROM Datamining.dbo.Registry r
GROUP BY r.Date, r.Task_Name, r.Student_Name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a windowed sum

```sql
SELECT   r.Date
         , r.Task_Name[Task Performed]
         , r.Student_Name [Name]
         , COUNT(*) [Count]
         , SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY r.Date) TotalCountByDate         
FROM Datamining.dbo.Registry r
GROUP BY r.Date, r.Task_Name, r.Student_Name
```